# service application in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Im new to sharepoint. i have a small problem, i have created a customer service application and deploey it to sharepoint and tested it, and everything worked fine for me. now i checked the IIS and under Sharepoint Web Services i couldn't find my service, can anybody tell what can be the cause for such an issue and how i can see the guid of my service under Sharepoint Web Services in IIS. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your service application endpoint will appear under SharePoint Web Services on all servers that have an instance of your service running. You can find the actual URI using this PowerShell:

```
$sa=get-SPServiceApplication -Name "The Name of your service application"
$sa.DefaultEndPoint.ListenUris
```

This will return the uri for your service endpoint (which you can normally point a browser at depending on how you've setup your endpoint). You'll notice that the URL contains a GUID and this GUID is specific to your service application instance. If you create another instance of your service application it'll have a different ID and therefore a different endpoint URL